# Encrypted columns in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have to retrieve data from database (`db1`) which has encrypted columns. I have written a stored procedure (as my query has lot of temp tables) to extract data from `db1` and insert it into tables in database `db2`.

In SSIS package or direct insert from SQL Server, I get this error:

> operand type clash: nvarchar(255) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'randomized', encryption_algorithm_name = 'aead_aes_256_cbc_hmac_sha_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'columnencryptionkey', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'db1') is incompatible with nvarchar

I have tried using ado.net connection but no success. I would really appreciate any help here. I have installed certificate on my machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your ```column_encryption_key_name``` spelled correctly?  ```coloumnencryptionkey```

Comment: I have chnaged the name as I cannot share it here